# Block animation delay working fine on OS 4.3 but not on 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Okay, so I choose to animate my label using block animation.

The logic is quite simple, I have a chart bar made of buttons, when the button is pressed, it create a label with no width, and then at the same method, the animation start to lengthen the label so that the words inside the label came out, and then after a brief 2.5 seconds delay, the label shrink again and removed from the superview.

The problem is :

- **The delay is working properly in OS 4.3**.
  The animation works as intended, it shows the label, after 2.5 it fires the next animation and closed the label.
- **The delay is ignored in OS 5.0**.
  After the first animation complete, it didn't wait for the delay, instead, fires the next animation blocks immediately.

Here is some of my code regarding the animation:

```
UILabel *lbl = [self createLabelWithText:numString frame:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 0, 10) bold:YES font:@"Helvetica" fontSize:10 color:[UIColor whiteColor] textAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft andTag:987];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [lbl setAlpha:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
     {
         [lbl setFrame:lblRect];
     }completion:^(BOOL finished) 
     {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:2.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
         {//here the second animation delay run properly on 4.3 , but ignored at 5.0
             [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 0, 10)];
         }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [lbl removeFromSuperview];
         }];
     }];
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit : in case of any of you wondering why this person didn't search on google or other stackoverflow questions, in fact, I did, and sadly all the posts I found doesn't provide me with answers I needed. :(

Comment: Are you doing this in a thread other than main? Try wrapping your code in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* code here */ });` call, and see what happens

Comment: i've tried that before, it's even worse, the animation got stuck and it won't load the completed block code

Comment: nevermind, i found the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i've found the problem. it's not exactly the blocks animation's fault, rather it's the error that occures because i set my animation to shrink my uilabel to width "0". turns out in IOS 5.0 (in my project at least) because i set my label size by using constraint, when i tried to shrink the label, as soon as it reads the label aren't suffice to show the entire text, it immediately terminate the label it self.